# 'LVS_EX_FULLROWSELECT' was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, winapi

I have code like this and I get 2 errors:

- " [Error] 'LVS_EX_FULLROWSELECT' was not declared in this scope "
- " [Error] 'ListView_SetExtendedListViewStyle' was not declared in this scope "

I've tried to define it like this: "#define LVS_EX_FULLROWSELECT 32", but it doesn't work:(

Code as below:

```
    if(LOWORD( wParam ) == 103 ){
GetClientRect( hwnd, & rcl );
HWND hListView = CreateWindowEx( 0, WC_LISTVIEW, NULL, WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | LVS_REPORT |
LVS_EDITLABELS, 0, 200, rcl.right - rcl.left, 300,
hwnd,( HMENU ) 1000, hInstance, NULL );


ListView_SetExtendedListViewStyle( hListView, LVS_EX_FULLROWSELECT );
//POCZĄTEK NAZW KOLUMN
lvc.mask = LVCF_WIDTH | LVCF_TEXT | LVCF_SUBITEM;


lvc.iSubItem = 0;
lvc.cx = 200;
lvc.pszText = "Player";
ListView_InsertColumn( hListView, 0, & lvc );

lvc.iSubItem = 1;
lvc.cx = 100;
lvc.pszText = "Number of games";
ListView_InsertColumn( hListView, 1, & lvc );

lvc.iSubItem = 2;
lvc.cx = 60;
lvc.pszText = "In game";
ListView_InsertColumn( hListView, 2, & lvc );


//KONIEC NAZW KOLUMN


//POCZĄTEK DODAWANIA ZAWARTOŚCI


lvi.mask = LVIF_TEXT;

for (int i=0; i<1000; i++) {
ostringstream i1a;
i1a << i;
string i1b = i1a.str();

TCHAR *player=new TCHAR[i1b.size()+1];
player[i1b.size()]=0;
copy(i1b.begin(),i1b.end(),player);

lvi.iItem = i;
lvi.pszText = player;
lvi.iSubItem = 0;
ListView_InsertItem( hListView, & lvi );




ListView_SetItemText( hListView, 0, 1, "15" );
ListView_SetItemText( hListView, 0, 2, "3" );
ListView_SetItemText( hListView, 1, 1, "15" );
ListView_SetItemText( hListView, 1, 2, "6" );
}

break;
}
```

Comment: #include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <CommCtrl.h>

Comment: Make sure `_WIN32_IE` is at least 0x0300.

Comment: Where did you get your SDK from?

Comment: I got it from the internet.

Comment: That doesn't really narrow it down very much. Is it up to date? Is it the MS SDK? Does your `CommCtrl.h` define `LVS_EX_FULLROWSELECT`?

Comment: Yes there is " #define LVS_EX_FULLROWSELECT 32 " in commctrl.h. I am using dev c++ 5.2.0.3

Comment: @MarcinKostrzewa chris is spot-on. you enable certain features in commctrl.h by way of various `#define`s, among them, `#define _WIN32_IE 0x0300` (or higher) to bring those macros into the compilation. There are likely more than this you probably need to consider, and is one of the reasons for the "targetver.h" header generated with most recent project wizards with Visual Studio. 2010 or later.

Comment: I did it but I got same errors. Ive tried it in Visual Studio 2008 and it compiles and I have this styles in My ListView. Whats wrong with this DEV C++?

Answer (score 0):

```
#define _WIN32_IE 0x0300
```

This worked for me

Comment: Can you develop further your answer?